# Help to identify these components

Tags: identification, components

[image]

I need help to identify this component.

[image]

Comment: EEIR - Hi, (a) I fixed your question to display the image. (b) Your title says components (plural) but the photo seems to show only one. Which one is incorrect, title or photo? (c) The guidelines for asking identification questions are [here](https://electronics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6710). Although someone might identify it just from the photo, it will increase the chances of you getting an answer (and the question not being closed) if you supply as much detail as possible from that list e.g. the device where the component came from, photos of the original PCB, size measurements etc.

Comment: Welcome! Please crop your image. 90 % of it is useless.

Answer (score 3):

You will have to take mechanical and electrical measurements to confirm exactly what it is, but this is the style of part it is:

https://www.murata.com/en-us/api/pdfdownloadapi?cate=cgsubChipLCFilteCombined&partno=NFE61PT472C1H9%23

Comment: It's definitely Murata EMIFIL or similar from another manufacturer. However, there is no markings on it to know which exact model or properties it has.

Comment: How can you guy identify this type of componentes ?

Comment: How do we identify? Experience. We’ve seen/used these components before. This one is particularly unique. Rather than just show the component, show it mounted on the pcb as this gives us more context.

Comment: @Kartman I just added a new image of the PCB

Comment: @EEIR The datasheet gives mechanical dimensions, nominal capacitance, and inductance, or attenuation vs. frequency in a 50-ohm system. Such measurements require at least a wideband AC voltmeter and signal generator, or function generator and oscilloscope, or network analyzer, etc. The analysis methods are standard EE stuff, sinusoidal steady state, etc.

Comment: Alternately, an approximate or representative value can be obtained from reverse-engineering the board, which will require as many of its specifications as can be determined, plus much better up-close photographs of top and bottom to identify ICs and components, and follow PCB traces.  Components may also need to be desoldered to see underneath them, or X-ray testing or destructive means (e.g. grinding down the PCB to view inner layers) may also be required, if it's a multilayer board. This would be a separate question; but also much more effort than most users would consider worth answering.