# Need help identifying this component!

Tags: pcb, identification, components

I am working on a reverse engineering project of a pressure gage sensor, and none of us seem to be able to identify this component. There are 3 traces to it on the pcb, center is ground and the poles on each side lead to the power and signal wires. Any help is greatly appreciated[image: component as removed from circuit]

Comment: 1. Please crop photos to the relevant portion; 2. What is the context for this component? In other words, what components was it connected to on the PCB?

Comment: It looks similar to the Murata EMIFIL parts discussed here: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/672114/help-to-identify-these-components but placing it between the power and signal lines doesn't make much sense to me.